# Should be 0 if no records found in the result through SQL query

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I am using Firebird. I need the below result, but I don't get what I need. I tried the below query.

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pd.Date)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
    WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
    WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
    WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
    WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
  END AS "MONTH",
  Count(distinct pd.numbers) AS "Count"       
FROM Power_D pd 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pd.Date) = '2016' 
AND pd.Name = 'Test' 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pd.Date)
```

For this query result below.

```
February    330
March       212
April       178
May         222
June        487
July        695
August      433
September   757
October     1307
November    321
December    143
```

But I need like below.

```
January     0
February    330
March       212
April       178
May         222
June        487
July        695
August      433
September   757
October     1307
November    321
December    143
```

Comment: Instead of a case expression, a small table holding the relationship of the month number to the month name, from which you can left outer join to your `power_d` table on column `month(pd.Date)` would do just that. In short, it's difficult to make records from no records, so having a record in another table (perhaps even a date dimension table) that can generate a month with an aggregate of `0`, is the right direction. *What RDBMS are you using (sql server, mysql, postgres, oracle, etc)?*

Comment: Thanks. But, without disturbing existing querie can we do?

Comment: @NagRaju What do you mean by "without disturbing existing queries" ? Your existing query does not work for months without entries, so you will have to change it anyway.

Comment: is possible like condition like if. I can do in c# but i can't in query

Comment: Being set-based, one needs a set to generate a set. If you can tell us what RDBMS you are using there may be a `generate_series()` type functionality that could quickly generate the jan-dec records necessary to perform the join that will solve the problem for you.

Comment: I am using Firebird sql

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution for MySQL/MariaDb based on @JNevill comment

```
SELECT m.month_name, count(distinct pd.numbers) AS "Count"
FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 AS month, 'January' as month_name
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'February'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'March'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'April'
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'May'
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'June'
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'July'
    UNION ALL SELECT 8, 'August'
    UNION ALL SELECT 9, 'September'
    UNION ALL SELECT 10, 'October'
    UNION ALL SELECT 11, 'November'
    UNION ALL SELECT 12, 'December'
    
) m

LEFT JOIN 

(
    SELECT *    
    FROM Power_D 
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) = '2016' 
      AND Name = 'Test' 
      
) pd ON EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pd.Date) = m.month

GROUP BY m.month_name
ORDER BY m.month
```

Comment: still not getting empty one in result

Comment: For Firebird, this solution will need to add `from RDB$DATABASE` to each of those selects (Firebird doesn't allow a select without a from-clause, and `RDB$DATABASE` is a built-in table guaranteed to have one row)

Comment: That's the case when funny table containing days of week can be useful if Firebird can do outer hash join with pre-aggregated stream.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this is to follow @JNevill's suggestion - this is a common problem and the solution is a standard pattern. Also, there is probably a standard function that will give you the month name, rather than the number, so you wouldn't need the CASE statement - but as you haven't tagged your question with the DBMS you are using it is impossible to know.

Anyway, something like the following should work - you'll probably need to adjust it for your specific DBMS:

```
with month_list(month_name) as
        select *
        from values
        ('January'),
        ('February'),
        ('March'),
        ('April'),
        ('May'),
        ('June'),
        ('July'),
        ('August'),
        ('September'),
        ('October'),
        ('November'),
        ('December')
    )
    SELECT 
    ml.month_name
    Count(distinct pd.numbers) AS "Count"       
    FROM month_limit ml
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Power_D pd on ml.month_name = TO_CHAR(pd.Date,'MMMM')
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pd.Date) = '2016' 
    AND pd.Name = 'Test' 
    GROUP BY  ml.month_name
    ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Firebird doesn't support table value constructors (`VALUES (...), (...)`).

Comment: Hence my comment "you'll probably need to adjust it for your specific DBMS" - as at the time I wrote the answer the questioner hadn't tagged their question with the DBMS they were using

Answer (score 0):

The results of your query suggest there is no data for January 2016, so there is also no row for the aggregate result. If you want to make up for this, you need to left or right join with a suitable source to produce the rows.

For example:

```
with recursive MONTHS as (
  select 1 as "MONTH", cast('January' as varchar(9)) "NAME" from RDB$DATABASE
  union all
  select 
    "MONTH" + 1, 
    decode("MONTH" + 1, 
      1, 'January', 2, 'February', 3, 'March', 
      4, 'April', 5, 'May', 6, 'June', 
      7, 'July', 8, 'August', 9, 'September',
      10, 'October', 11, 'November', 12, 'December')
  from MONTHS
  where "MONTH" < 12
),
DATA as (
  select
    extract(month from pd.Date) as "MONTH",
    count(distinct pd.numbers) as "Count"       
  from Power_D pd 
  where extract(year from pd.Date) = 2016
  and pd.Name = 'Test' 
  group by extract(month from pd.Date)
)
select 
  m."NAME" as "MONTH",
  coalesce(d."Count", 0) as "Count"
from MONTHS m
natural left join DATA d
order by m."MONTH"
```

This example uses a recursive common table expression to generate the months. I think this is less verbose than using a lot of `union all` as in the answer by Pippo.

However, that can be achieved with:

```
with MONTHS as (
  select 1 as "MONTH", 'January' as "NAME" from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 2, 'February' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 3, 'March' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 4, 'April' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 5, 'May' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 6, 'June' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 7, 'July' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 8, 'August' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 9, 'September' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 10, 'October' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 11, 'November' from RDB$DATABASE
  union all select 12, 'December' from RDB$DATABASE
)
-- ... rest same as previous example
```

Firebird requires a from-clause with a select, and `RDB$DATABASE` is a table which is guaranteed to have one and only one row.

Answer (score -1):

Use a SQL COALESCE:

> COALESCE(Count(distinct pd.numbers), 0) AS "Count"

Comment: This won't work, unfortunately. There simply isn't a record in january to coalesce.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, got previous results only without January

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).